# How do I check if a file already has line with "contents" in it?

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep

I need to know if a file aready has line with contents X in it, if not append line. here's the code I've tried.

```
if ! $(grep 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/foo/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/foo)' ~/.bashrc)
then
    echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/foo/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/foo)' >> ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: I answered a similar question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479579/bash-script-only-echo-line-to-bash-profile-once-if-the-line-doesnt-yet-exist/4480671#4480671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

LINE='eval $(perl -I$HOME/foo/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/foo)'

if ! grep -qF "$LINE" file.txt ; then echo "$LINE" >> file.txt ; fi
```

The $(...) will return the result of the command, not the errorlevel value. Use without command substitution to get the proper return code.

Comment: The '!' command isn't always available in 'sh', IIRC (yeah, I know you used bash).  It might be slightly more idiomatic sh to say:

  grep -qF "$LINE" file.txt || echo "$LINE" >> file.txt

Comment: @Hari: `!` wasn't in Bourne, but it is in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

To search for a literal string:

```
line='eval $(perl -I$HOME/foo/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/foo)'
file=~/.bashrc
if ! grep -q -x -F -e "$line" <"$file"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$line" >>"$file"
fi
```

`-q` suppresses `grep` output (you're only interested in the return status). `-x` requires the whole line to match. `-F` searches for a literal string rather than a regexp. `-e` is a precaution in case `$line` starts with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with `awk`'s `index` function: it's an equivalent of `strstr`, so should be well-suited for comparision (as opposed to `grep` which is for pattern matching).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sed. The issue is that you need to include the string in the code twice. Once to test it, again to insert it.

```
sed -i '/eval \$(perl -I\$HOME\/foo\/lib\/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=\$HOME\/foo)/!{ ${ s/$/\neval \$(perl -I\$HOME\/foo\/lib\/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=\$HOME\/foo)/; }; }' /path/to/file
```